# Hide passwords in Buildbot shell commands from logs

Tags: buildbot

I need to be able to pass password to shell command but don't want it to be available in logs. I tried finding a solution and found something called an Obfuscated class in buildbot, but it seems i'm missing something it's not working and i couldn't find any examples.

Is their some other way or if this is the only way if someone could provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

secrets are supported in Buildbot since 0.9.7. http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/secretsmanagement.html

Using this api to access your secret will automatically make them redacted from the build logs.